# WIA driver close,OK,Cancel button handling

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, wia, windows-process

I am working on some modifications in WIA driver( VC6).
My modifications are done in the property sheet, the only area we can modify. But I have to do some changes in a bin file when the user clicks on the OK , Cancel or Close Button which is part of the WIA UI provided by Microsoft.

Can we handle these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can only alter the property sheet resource, then no. Changing a file requires code, and a property resource does not contain code.